# RewriteRule not working on host

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, host

The host does not work, but On local works

```
Options -Indexes 
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)

RewriteRule .* - [F]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+).html$ index.php?page=ista&link=$1 [L]
```

Comment: What URL is not working and what is error?

Comment: 404 Not Found show

example: www.site.com/help.html

Comment: Is `mod_rewrite` enabled on your host's server? You could also try adding `RewriteBase /` just after `RewriteEngine On` - some hosts seem to require this.

Comment: 404 Not Found
nginx

RewriteBase / not working

Comment: There's your problem right there. You are using nginx, not Apache. `.htaccess` does not work on Apache. Please see the [relevant documentation on nginx rewriting](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html).

Comment: please help me about nginx. what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved. Disable the host nginx